# Multi Project in 1 Solution for Typescript

Tags: typescript

This question isn't about modules or having several files in project. It is having MULTIPLE typescript projects in a SINGLE solution in visual studio.

Supposed i have Solution named Three_Proj, with proj_1, proj_2 and proj_3.
I want proj_1 to solely output javascripts written in typescript.

Proj_2 & 3 are also outputting javascripts BUT utilising codes from proj_1.ts to output proj_2.ts & proj_3.ts respectively. The referenced code WILL NOT be copied manually into the other 2 projects.

I am looking for something in typescript similar to the following constructs in various language:

```
C#, using
Java, import
C++, include
```

Is there a way proj_2 & 3 could call, using/import/include proj_1 directly? `///< reference path`, only links to the ts files in proj_1, not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply reference the `_references.ts` file of Project1 from project2 / proj3 `_references.ts` files. That would bring the code from proj1 to proj2/proj3